# Spresense Arduino 実行ファイルの動的変更について

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresenseを使用してArduino-IDE環境にてプログラムを作っています。

**質問**
・Arduino-IDEで出力した実行バイナリをSDカードなどに転送し、spresenseのFlashに書かれているプログラムのアップデートを行いたい

ESP32などではArduinoOTAなどの方法でFlashに書かれているプログラムの書き換えができるのですが、Spresense単体にてArduino部分のプログラムの書き換え方法はどう行うのでしょうか？

**開発環境**
・spresense本体＋spresense lte拡張ボード
・Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

Spresense SDK環境であれば、Linuxカーネルとアプリケーションが分離されているように、ローダブルなアプリケーションを作成することができます。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_ローダブルelfチュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%96%E3%83%ABelf%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB)
複数のアプリケーション(実行バイナリ)をSDカードに置いておいてアプリケーションを選択して動かすことができるので、質問にあるようなアップデートもアプリケーションを差し替えるだけで可能になると思います。

なんとなくピンポイントで質問への回答にはなっていない気はしますが...
自分が見る限りArduino環境ではこの機能はまだサポートされてなさそうです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
現在Spresense SDKに搭載されていない機能(ソフトウェアシリアル等)があり、
Arduino環境で作っています。
それらがクリアできればSpresenseSDKで作るのですが…